# View not getting detected and throwing whitelabel error (Spring Boot Application)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I just started learning spring boot, and created a small spring mvc application. But I'm getting white label error when I try to access view, but application is working fine if i just return the string using responseBody annotation. I have also added thymeleaf to dependency.

Project Structure:
[image]

```
demo2
|-- src/main/java
|   |-- example
|   |   `-- Demo2Application
|   |-- controller
|   |   `-- Controller
|   `-- model
|       `-- Person
`-- src/main/resources
    `-- templates
        `-- personView.html
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Application Config Main method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com", "example", "controller"})
public class Demo2Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping("/person")
    public String getPerson(Model model) {
        Person person = new Person();

        person.setFirstname("John");
        person.setLastName("Carter");
        person.setAge(25);
        model.addAttribute(person);

        return "personView";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public @ResponseBody String test() {
        return "hello world";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String entry() {
        return "Welcome to Spring Boot Application";
    }
}
```

View Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    FirstName : <span th:text="${person.firstName}"></span>
    LastName : <span th:text="${person.lastName}"></span>
    Age : <span th:text="${person.age}"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Sun Sep 04 22:45:31 EDT 2016
    There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
    No message available
```

Log:

```
2016-09-04 22:43:10.330  INFO 11356 --- [           main] com.example.Demo2Application             : Starting Demo2Application on Sais-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 11356 (/Users/sainishankbojja/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/demo2/target/classes started by sainishankbojja in /Users/sainishankbojja/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/demo2)
2016-09-04 22:43:10.334  INFO 11356 --- [           main] com.example.Demo2Application             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-04 22:43:10.370  INFO 11356 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@a9cd3b1: startup date [Sun Sep 04 22:43:10 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-04 22:43:11.353  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-04 22:43:11.365  INFO 11356 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-09-04 22:43:11.366  INFO 11356 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-09-04 22:43:11.430  INFO 11356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-04 22:43:11.430  INFO 11356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1063 ms
2016-09-04 22:43:11.558  INFO 11356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.561  INFO 11356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.562  INFO 11356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.562  INFO 11356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.562  INFO 11356 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.786  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@a9cd3b1: startup date [Sun Sep 04 22:43:10 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-04 22:43:11.834  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test]}" onto public java.lang.String controller.PersonController.test()
2016-09-04 22:43:11.835  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto java.lang.String controller.PersonController.entry()
2016-09-04 22:43:11.835  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/person]}" onto public java.lang.String controller.PersonController.getPerson(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2016-09-04 22:43:11.837  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-09-04 22:43:11.837  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-09-04 22:43:11.860  INFO 11356 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.860  INFO 11356 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.885  INFO 11356 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-04 22:43:11.990  INFO 11356 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-09-04 22:43:12.035  INFO 11356 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-04 22:43:12.038  INFO 11356 --- [           main] com.example.Demo2Application             : Started Demo2Application in 12.204 seconds (JVM running for 12.492)
2016-09-04 22:43:15.931  INFO 11356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-04 22:43:15.931  INFO 11356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-09-04 22:43:15.941  INFO 11356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 10 ms
```

Comment: What is the error log that the application is outputting?

Comment: just updated with the log there is some mapping error, not sure why it is causing

Comment: Is that how your project structure exactly looks like? Is it a `resources` or `src/main/resources`?

Comment: src/main/resources

Comment: updated project structure

Comment: can you show your application.properties file,please

Comment: Without seeing the actual error, it is more or less guessing what is wrong. What is it failing at, the execution of the controller, or the view resolution or... So post the actual errors from the server, not the startup messages.

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine for me (only a small issue with a capital letter "N" in `firstName`). So your problem is either in your environment/IDE or due to some settings you changed in application.properties.

Comment: I haven't written anything in application.properties @Patrick

Comment: Can you add `spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true` in your `application.properties` file and try it again

Comment: @Patrick I just enabled thymeleaf in application.properties but still not working. can you please tell me to get logs for this white label error?

Comment: can you tell me which request do you send.

Comment: @Patrik this is not a Restful application, I didn't get what you are asking for.. sorry for that still learning

Comment: @g00glen00b thanks for checking the code, not sure whats wrong with my IDE

Comment: my method is not detecting view page